# C# Generic class definition with inerited class syntax error

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, syntax, constructor

I've looked at a number of questions related to defining a generic class that inherits a base class, but did not see this case. (Sorry if I missed it.)

My class is a generic class. It inherits a concrete base class. The constructor for the base class takes arguments.

I can make the class definition work if I eliminate the generic specification, as follows:

```
public class DataItemType : DataItem 
{
    public DataItemType(string sNameArg, string sAddressArg, bool nWriteAllowedArg)
        : base(sNameArg, sAddressArg, nWriteAllowedArg)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the definition with the generic specification.

```
public class DataItemType<TValue> : DataItem where TValue : struct
{
    public DataItemType<TValue>(string sNameArg, string sAddressArg, bool nWriteAllowedArg)
        : base(sNameArg, sAddressArg, nWriteAllowedArg)
    {
    }
}
```

In the class definition line, the IDE complains that there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter sNameArg of the base class. The IDE offers to create the constructor. But when it does, the syntax fails. (The inserted constructor doesn't seem to make any sense, either, for what it's worth.)

Comment: Skip `<TValue>` from `DataItemType` constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `<TValue>` from the row of the constructor in the generic class:

```
public class DataItem
{
    public DataItem(string sNameArg, string sAddressArg, bool nWriteAllowedArg) {}
}

public class DataItemType<TValue> : DataItem where TValue : struct
{
    public DataItemType(string sNameArg, string sAddressArg, bool nWriteAllowedArg) 
        : base(sNameArg, sAddressArg, nWriteAllowedArg)
    {
    }
}
```

The use of the `TValue` in the generic class is for parameters you pass to functions or return values. But not on the constructor.

You are confusion it with adding the `<>` after a function. Adding it there means that the function itself is generic and can receive different types.

- For Generics on methods see [Generic Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)
- For Generics on classes see [Generic Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx)

If for example you want to receive a parameter in the constructor that is from the generic type then:

```
public class DataItemType<TValue> : DataItem where TValue : struct
{
    public DataItemType(TValue someParameter, string sNameArg, string sAddressArg, bool nWriteAllowedArg)
        : base(sNameArg, sAddressArg, nWriteAllowedArg)
    {
    }

    //Note that as in the constructor you can use this generic type for the function
    public void SomeFunction(TValue value) { }

    //Or define a new generic type which will be only in the scope of this function
    public void SomeOtherFunction<TValue2>(TValue2 value2) { }
}
```

Comment: You are right. I did read the pages on Generic Classes and Generic Methods, several times. I took the generic parameter in the class definition to be part of the class name. The constructor must have the same name as the class, so I put the generic parameter in the constructor name. I don't see anything in the online Programming Guide to correct that misconception. The C# Specification is not obvious on the point, imo.

Comment: @GregoryAshmore - I can see where the misunderstanding comes from :) Glad you managed to solve it with my answer